# Checking image size via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-plugins, dimensions

I need to check the dimensions of an image by javascript (the image is not attached to the DOM anywhere yet), and do so by a load() event on the image.

The variable IMAGE below contains a valid image url.
The variable SELF below contains a reference to THIS of the plugin.

The problem is that from within the load event I don't have access to the variables of my jQuery plugin. And from outside of the load event, I don't have access to the image dimensions checked by that event.

Gives me dimensions but no access to the plugin scope

```
            //Find dimensions of image
            var imageTest = new Image(), iWidth, iHeight;
            // just in case it is not already loaded
            $(imageTest).load(function () {
                iWidth = imageTest.width;
                iHeight = imageTest.height;
                alert(iWidth+' x '+iHeight);
                alert(self.data('overlayTypePreview'));
            });
            imageTest.src = image;
```

Gives me access to the plugin scope, but not to the image dimensions:

```
            //Find dimensions of image
            var imageTest = new Image(), iWidth, iHeight;
            // just in case it is not already loaded
            $(imageTest).load(function () {
                iWidth = imageTest.width;
                iHeight = imageTest.height;
            });
            imageTest.src = image;

            alert( self.data('overlayTypePreview') ); // <-- gives me the correct data, string 'mainOverlay'
            alert(iWidth+' x '+iHeight); // <-- gives me 'undefined x undefined'
```

I also tried the ugly hackish solution of going via window, but that didn't work for me either, perhaps because the code supposed to do the alerting triggers before the load event?

```
            //Find dimensions of image
            var imageTest = new Image(), iWidth, iHeight;
            // just in case it is not already loaded
            $(imageTest).load(function () {
                window.iWidth = imageTest.width;
                window.iHeight = imageTest.height;
            });
            imageTest.src = image;

            alert(window.iWidth+' x '+window.iHeight);
```

I suppose I could set up a system of 3 functions passing the thread to each other, but from the load event there is no way of calling the instance of my jquery-plugin right? (seeing I don't know what the user will instantiate the plugin as, otherwise I could have hard-coded the instance name, if I wanted an even uglier solution).

I suppose I could set up some sort of timeout-ping:ing of the image from inside the plugin instead of using the load() event but I thought there might be a smarter way that I didn't think of yet...

Comment: What is the *"plugin scope"*? are you talking about the `this` of your plugin?

Comment: Yes, I use this.data('variable') for most plugin-variables (and functions as well).

Comment: Outside the load function, save the reference : `var self = this;`. Then, inside the load, you can do `self.imgW = this.width`. The value will be saved in your plugin. Just remember that `load` is asynchronous.

Comment: That would be almost equivalent to the window.iWidth option I posted above (though your version is a bit cleaner), and works just as poorly, meaning I would still need some sort of ping:ing to see when the variable is actually populated since it's asynchronous like you say. So it doesn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: You could maybe edit the plugin's code to fit your needs, and add your load() stuff...?

Comment: Jeremy could you expand on that?

Comment: Well, first of, that's not the same as putting a property into the window since `self` would be the plugin while window is global. Multiple instances of your plugin would cause issues in the window variable, not in the plugin instance. Then, if that doesn't solve you issue, then nothing will. load will always be asynchronous, so you need to called a function after the load event that will do what you have to do once you got the image dimension. By the way, using a variable to reference your plugin is a good practice. Especially if your plugin has events (like `.load`).

Comment: Karl, how do you mean using a variable to reference your plugin, do you mean like you used the SELF or something different?

Comment: @MattiasSvensson Using `self`. Here an example of a well constructed plugin : http://jsfiddle.net/fcL7fzt2/1/

Comment: It seems I can access the html object by use of SELF in the load event, but not the plugin scope. For example, I have a variable that I usually reference like this: self.data('overlayTypePreview') But that only gives 'undefined' when used from inside of the load event.

Comment: @MattiasSvensson It shouldn't, can you show me? jsFiddle perhaps?

Comment: Don't pass self in the load function, it override the declared var containing the plugin.

Comment: Ah, that seems to have been the issue... will run some tests, brb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving it. Like I stated in my initial question, a series of 3 functions was necessary to make this clean:

In my plugin, to draw a preview of an image I make this call:

```
self.data('drawPreview')(self,entityId);
```

The drawPreview function however is only going to bounce the execution on to the isImageGreaterThanOverlay test

```
var drawPreview = function(self,entityId){

    self.data('isImageGreaterThanOverlay')(self,entityId,'drawPreview2')

}
this.data('drawPreview',drawPreview);
```

If I had only used the isImageGreaterThanOverlay() function for the drawPreview() function I could have put all of the contents of the isImageGreaterThanOverlay() righ inside the drawPreview above, but since I want to be able to use this tester for other similar functions as well, I keep it separate like this.

As seen below, my tester function declares a new Image, then attaches a load event to that image, then actually loads the image, which triggers the anonymous function inside the load event.

```
var isImageGreaterThanOverlay = function(self,entityId,destination){
    //Find dimensions of image
    var imageTest = new Image(), iWidth, iHeight;

    $(imageTest).load(function () {
        var iWidth = imageTest.width;
        var iHeight = imageTest.height;

        //find dimensions of overlay
        var myOverlay = self.data('overlayTypePreview');
        oWidth = parseInt( $(self).find(".VanillaGallery-"+myOverlay).css("width").replace('px', '') );
        oHeight = parseInt( $(self).find(".VanillaGallery-"+myOverlay).css("width").replace('px', '') );

        if (iWidth > oWidth || iHeight > oHeight) {
            var isGreater = true;
        }
        else {
            var isGreater = false;
        }

        self.data(destination)(self,entityId,isGreater);

    });

    var entity = self.data('findTheObject')(self,entityId);
    var image = entity['path'];
    imageTest.src = image;

}
this.data('isImageGreaterThanOverlay',isImageGreaterThanOverlay);
```

This is important because doing this in any other way would risk the image not being fully loaded in the browser when the code tries to read the dimensions of the image.

Key to making this work in a jQuery plugin is including the reference to the jQuery plugins's THIS like karl-andré-gagnon suggested in his comment. Through that reference, you can access the variables and functions of your plugin scope. It is how I compare the image against the overlay size (stored in my plugin's variable) and also how I pass execution back to a function inside my plugin from the load-event's anonymous function.

Also make sure you don't pass a THIS-reference (in my case SELF) in the load-events anonymous function but do it as I have done, just write it inside the anonymous function.

So when the load-events anonymous function is done checking the sizes, it passes execution on to a function that I call drawPreview2 (since it is the second part of my initial drawPreview function, remember I had to split it up because of the asynchronous load-event)

```
var drawPreview2 = function(self,entityId,isGreater){

    //using the passed in 'isGreater' variable,
    //I do the stuff I need to display the image correctly

}
this.data('drawPreview2',drawPreview2);
```